# Visual Studio 2015 link against MFC42

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2015

i recently continued a project i once developed with Visual Studio 6 using MFC.
I didn't touch the code for at least 4 Years.
It all compiled well on VS6.
But now i installed VS2015, converted the project and fixed some code which won't compile on VS2015 any more.
So everything went well. But when I tried to start the exe on a clean Windows 10 System it said the the runtime dlls are missing (e.g. MFC140u.dll)
I know that I can install the VC++ distributable to get my application working, but the size of my application is only 325kB.
But I can see that the MFC42u.dll is on this blank Win 10 System. So there's already a VC++ runtime including the MFC.
I simply don't want to install a new VC++ runtime on every system, why not using the existing one?

Can anyone please tell me how to link against the MFC42 when using VS2015?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as i am aware you will need to include the MFC14 dll's with the exe. MFC42 relates to VS6. As you have now compiled with VS2015 your application now uses MFC14 dlls. Can you not package those up with the installer?

Comment: Packaging approx 5mb for a application of 325kb? Thats no option for me. I still can compile the application with VS6 and it will run, but that's somehow not the workflow i'm happy with.

Comment: Static linking the MFC isn't an option?

Comment: I chose 'Use MFC in a Static Library' in project settings, but that did not change anything. The blank win10 system still moans about missing MFC dlls. Even the exe is the same size as if I chose 'Use MFC in a Shared Dll'

Comment: That file was meant for Microsoft's private use, it is not intended to be used by general applications.  You don't have the import library for it so you can't convince the linker to use it.  Just running the [redist installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) is the very trivial solution.

Comment: Yeah, but as I wrote, to require installing a >5mb library to use my small ~500kb application is in no way an option for me. So problably I gotta stick to building releases on XP with VS6, and developing/debugging on VS2015.

Comment: If changing from a DLL to static linking doesn't have any observable effect, then you messed up your build system. Linking statically against the MFC library doesn't require any MFC DLLs to be installed on the target machine. You'll still need the CRT, though. However, you can also statically link against the CRT.

Comment: If you are going to complain about a 5mb install, then don't use a big UI library (when Visual Studio 6 was new, did the base OS include the MFC libraries... don't think so!). So either strip down to pure Win API, just install the libraries, or keep using VS 6. (and MFC42 is *old*!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wonder why this Q has been downvoted.
But the answer is: It's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to package the vc redistributables, have 'em downloaded from Microsoft during installation!

In an [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) script with [InnoSetup Dependency Installer](https://github.com/stfx/innodependencyinstaller) this would look like

```
[Languages]
Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "de"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"

[Code]
// shared code for installing the products
#include "scripts\products.iss"
// helper functions
#include "scripts\products\stringversion.iss"
#include "scripts\products\winversion.iss"
#include "scripts\products\fileversion.iss"
// actual products       
#include "scripts\products\msiproduct.iss"
#include "scripts\products\vcredist2015.iss"

// Perform some initializations.  Return False to abort setup
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  initwinversion();
  SetForceX86(true); // force 32-bit install of next products
  vcredist2015();
  SetForceX86(false); // disable forced 32-bit install again
end;
```

given that your app is still only 32bit after upgrading from VS6.